# Why is float casted from string from UITextField input rounded to the lower integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, casting, floating-point

I have a UITextField, where the user can enter a decimal number.

I assume that input is a string in objectiv-c, so I cast it to float, but instead of getting the correct decimal number, I am getting a float rounded to the lower interger, i.e. user enters 1,8 and I get 1,000000

My code:

```
float groesse = [self.groesseTextField.text floatValue];
```

How can I get the correct 1,8?

Comment: Change `,` to `.` or use a different parser to parse the decimal value.  (NSString floatValue is not locale sensitive.)

Comment: Do you have any reason why you are using float with about six digits precision instead of double with 15 digits precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `floatValue` to parse a user entered number to a `float`. You need to use an `NSNumberFormatter`. The number formatter will properly deal with locale specific number formats. `floatValue` only works with numbers that use a period for the decimal separator and no other markup such as grouping separators. `NSNumberFormatter` can handle all of this.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *val = [formatter numberFromString:self.groesseTextField.text];
float groesse = [val floatValue];
```

Comment: Thx, you are right. But the correct selector is numberFromString instead numberFromText: `NSNumber *val = [formatter numberFromString:self.groesseTextField.text];`

Comment: Good answer. (Ignoring the typo.) Voted.